# Seperate database connection function from the query function

Tags: mysql, go

I have been trying to execute queries with http://www.github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and have been following this tutorial: https://tutorialedge.net/golang/golang-mysql-tutorial/

Now this tutorial does everything in 1 custom function, but I've tried to split up opening the database connection and the queries itself in seperate functions. The way I've done this is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type SqlResult struct {
  id int
}

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
  dbConnection:= openDatabaseConnection();
  getID(dbConnection);

}

func openDatabaseConnection() *sql.DB {
  db,err:= sql.Open("mysql","username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test");

  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }

  defer db.Close()
  return db
}

func getID(db *sql.Db) {
  results,err:= db.Query("SELECT id FROM test")
  for results.Next() {
    var result SqlResult
    err=results.Scan(&result.id)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Print(result.id)
  }
}
```

This doesn't print out anything but also doesn't give an error.

Now when I put my code in 1 function, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type SqlResult struct {
  id int
}

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
  openDatabaseConnection();
}

func openDatabaseConnection() *sql.DB {
  db,err:= sql.Open("mysql","username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test");

  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }

  results,err:= db.Query("SELECT id FROM test")
  for results.Next() {
    var result SqlResult
    err=results.Scan(&result.id)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Print(result.id)
  }

  defer db.Close()
  return db
}
```

This returns me all the id's, but I want to split the functionality up. It doesn't seem like opening the database connection everytime I need a new query is the right solution.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my first example and if so, what would be the right way of the way I want it to be?

Comment: You code would not compile: E.g. in `var db *sql.db`  you cannot  use unexported stuff.

Comment: @Flimzy What do you mean? The 2nd example does run. The first one just returns empty in command line(?). Even when I define dbConnection as a `*sql.DB`

Comment: Also `defer db.Close()` in your `openDatabaseConnection` function means that you'll always close your connection immediately after opening it, before returning it.

Comment: @Flimzy Sorry I had the `dbConnection:=`  part commented out for testing purposes

Comment: @Loko: Like I said: _Paste your actual code_

Comment: In your both code examples, your global `var db *sql.DB` (you actually wrote `*sql.db`, which is invalid, and won't compile) is entirely unused. Why does it exist?

Comment: @Flimzy Sorry If I misunderstand but `var db *sql.DB` would provide the variable `db` as a global variable so that I could use it in seperate functions right?

Comment: Yes, I see that `var db *sql.DB` is global--but it's not used. In both examples, you're only using the local instance of `db` with your `db, err := ...` declaration (the `:=` declares the new copy of db as a local variable)

Comment: @Flimzy You mean I reassign the variable `db` with `db,err :=...` and never using it globally anywhere? So the global variable has no use?

Comment: @Loko: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"what would be the right way of the way I want it to be?"*

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    db = openDatabaseConnection()
    defer db.Close()
    
    printIds(db)
}

func openDatabaseConnection() *sql.DB {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return db
}

func printIds(db *sql.DB) {
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        if err := rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(id)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so this worked. I have put the `defer db.close()` in the `main` func and in the `getID` func and removed it from the `openDatabaseConnect` func. Was that the problem then I guess?

Comment: @Loko In `getID` you need to defer close the **`rows`** returned from `Query`, if you don't you'll leak connections and crash your program eventually. `db.Close` is not really necessary, as any connections retained by the program will be released when the program exits, i.e. when `main` exits.

Comment: @Loko deferred functions are executed when the surrounding function exits, so if you have `defer db.Close` in `openDatabaseConnect` then you effectively rendered that function worthless because as soon as it exits it closes the db it just opened.

Comment: @Loko note that I left the global `db` in the code only because I assume that in an actual project you would like to use it and you're interested in how to properly intialize it, however, as pointed out by Flimzy, in the example it is unused, even when correctly initialized you're still passing the returned instance directly to the `getID` function which does not, and has no reason to, touch the global.

Comment: Ah I understand it now.